# cakephp ignores form input type "number"

Tags: html, cakephp-2.0, forms, html-input

What I am trying to do is get a form field which only allows numbers to be input into but when I try this:

```
<?php 
echo $this->Form->input('aht',array(
    'label' => 'AHT',
    'type' => 'number',
    'required' => true 
));
?>
```

cakephp outputs:

```
<div class="input number">
  <label for="aht">AHT</label>
  <input id="aht" type="text" required="required" name="data[aht]">
</div>
```

instead of the HTML 5 input type "number".
When trying to use other types like text it's working fine.
Any ideas?

CakePHP version is 2.5.4

Answer (score 0):

Change your `aht` field in the database to type `INT` and this should happen "auto-magically".

If this is already the case, try adding some validation in the model to define the data type e.g.

```
public $validate = array(
    'aht' => array(
        'numeric' => array(
            'rule' => array('numeric'),
            'message' => 'AHT should be numeric',
        ),
    )
);
```

Comment: The aht-field is not a table-column. It is just for a simple calculation. Forgot to mention that.